# objectId.isValid is not a function in making API requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I am trying to make individual API get requests in server.js but I don't get the desired results. The error that I get in Postman is as followed:

**objectId.isValid is not a function in making API request**

Here is the code of server.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb');
var mongoose=require('./db/mongoose');
var Todo=require('./models/todo');
var User=require('./models/user');
var app = express();
app.get('/todos/:id', (req, res) => {
  var id=req.params.id;

  if (!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }

  Todo.findById(id).then((todo) => {
    if (!todo) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.send({todo});
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});
```

Comment: You are requiring the whole mongo lib and saving it in `ObjectID`. Try: `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID`

Comment: Yes,it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is answered in the comments. Writing a detailed answer to help completeness of this post.

`ObjectID` is a property of the object returned by `require('mongodb')`, which is why `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID` works fine.

If you switch to ES6, object destructuring assignment comes handy.

```
const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb');
```

- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/ObjectID.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked like charm :)